# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout How do I fix?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I got this error in android studio:
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

  
      recyclerView_main.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    //recyclerView_main.adapter =MainAdapter()

    fetchJson()
}

  fun fetchJson(){
    val url = "there is url here"
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val body = response.body?.string()
            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val homeFeed = gson.fromJson(body,HomeFeed::class.java)
            runOnUiThread{
                recyclerView_main.adapter=MainAdapter(homeFeed)
            }
            //println(body)


           // recyclerView_main.adapter=MainAdapter(homeFeed)



          /*  runOnUiThread(
                Runnable {
                    recyclerView_main.adapter=MainAdapter(homeFeed)
                }

            )*/


        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            println("Failed")
        }
    })


}
```

}

class  HomeFeed(val results: List, val user_id: Int,)

class Content(val title: String,
val body: String,
val images: List
)

class Image(val image_name: String,
val h_link: String
)

Comment: are you getting valid response ?? have you checked your api response ??

Comment: try `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`